# Como insertar en un array de objectos solamente los objetos de otro array de objetos? JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

quiero saber si hay una manera de insertar solamente los objetos de un array de objetos en otro array de objetos sin tener que hacer un ciclo for, ya que en js si insertas un array de objetos en un array de objetos insertas todo el array, no los objetos solamente de ese array que es lo que quiero yo, gracias :)

Comment: Estas preguntando como destapar una botella de vino sin tener el sacacorchos.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un [mcve]? Saludos

Comment: jajjaa, lo se, pero no se me ocurre otra manera mas que hacer el ciclo for, solo preguntaba si existe otra manera xD

Comment: Por qué ocupas que nos ea con un cliclo `for`?. Esa es la única manera que se me ocurre.

Comment: Sin ver la estructura de lo que tienes, y lo que quieres, imposible decirte. ¿Acaso el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) no es lo que necesitas? Saludos

Comment: Hay muchas formas de agregar "cosas" a un arreglo en `JS`. Por ejemplo con `while`, `foreach`, `map`, `splice`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una Función recursiva     [link](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Que-es-la-recursividad-o-recursion-Un-ejemplo-con-JavaScript.aspx#:%7E:text=La%20recursividad%20consiste%20en%20funciones,factorial%20de%20un%20n%C3%BAmero%20entero.) pero es reinventar la rueda y no creo que sea optimo.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var coloresFrutas = ["Rojo", "Blanco", "Morado"];

function recorsArray(numeroToTalVueltas, numeroActualVueltas){

  coloresFrutas.push(fruits[numeroActualVueltas])
  numeroActualVueltas++;
  
  if((numeroToTalVueltas)>numeroActualVueltas){
    //Función recursiva
    recorsArray(numeroToTalVueltas, numeroActualVueltas)
  }
  return coloresFrutas; 
}


console.log(recorsArray(fruits.length,0));
```

Por otro lado si siempre vas a añadir la misma cantidad de elementos al array puedes hacer un

```
tuArray.push(segundoArray[0]);
tuArray.push(segundoArray[1]);
tuArray.push(segundoArray[2]);
tuArray.push(segundoArray[3]);
```

Pero esto tampoco es optimo ya que tienes una cantidad especifica de `push()`

***La solución que buscas la pongo al final esta función internamente (creo que hace un bucle no estoy seguro) pero es la forma mas sencilla de anidar dos arrays sin bucles. [Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat)***

```js
var list = ["foo", "bar"];
var newlist = list.concat( ["baz", "qux"] );
console.log(newlist)
```

Comment: Creo que @plus busca una manera automatizada, la manera que pones en tu respuesta con push se automatizaría con un ciclo `for`. Lo que dices de `concat()`, añade el array entero, @push solo quiere añadir los objetos que contiene el array. Tu respuesta responde a lo contrario de las especificaciones de la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: @gabrielcoronel creo que lo he entendido bien lo que le ocurre es que @plus hace es lista.push(listaDos) esto lo que hace es meter un ultimo elemento que es el array completo que se le pasa y el usuario quiere insertar solo los elementos como hace concat 
 --> `var list = ["foo", 1,4];
var newlist = list.concat( ["baz", "qux"] );
console.log(newlist)`